# Using a UUID as a primary key for small SQL tables

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I've read that UUIDs are typically not recommended as a primary key due to size and performance issues on large data sets.

However, would it be detrimental at all to use it on a few of the top level organizational tables? E.g. *Organization* or *Branch*, where there are only a handful of entries?

Comment: Do you mean GUID's? In short, no. But then you might need to reflect that in the transactional table. Also you should keep things consistent in your DB. PK's are either identities or GUID's, not a mix. If you have a good reason for a GUID - i.e. the record must be universally unique then by all means use it. But if you're just doing that to avoid modelling your data properly then it's bad design practice.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of the question. Disk space is cheap, and as a primary key the UUIDs should be well indexed and performant.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid UUID and GUID are the same thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Oops I missed this is Postgres which I know very little about.

Comment: @ceejayoz - it's not just a disk space issue. I'd be interested in hearing the reason for needing a UUID in a small/static table. What's the advantage? Do you want to put the UUID in everywhere it's referenced?

Comment: @Greg As an example, using a UUID for a `clients` table means the URL `clients/df3b1e6f-30b1-489f-a61d-f3bf2e4f1046` doesn't reveal the number of clients you have, whereas `clients/12` gives some info on that. It has some value.

Comment: That's exactly it, for the top level tables it would be great not to be able to gleam any information from the ID.

Comment: The example of "Branch" isn't really a secret is it? Most companies have their branches on their public websites. But in any case I would put a secondary unique key in the database as the UUID but I wouldn't use it as a primary key.

Comment: We haven't found any issues with using guids. See this algorithm https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database. I ran a test with ~4M rows; seemed OK. For small data sets I'd be surprised if you noticed a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `serial` instead of UUIDs.  Why are integers preferable to UUIDs?

- They occupy less space.  This is a marginal consideration in the base table, but a bigger issue for foreign keys.
- Integers are easier to read and remember.

In many databases, tables are physically ordered using primary keys.  In such databases, new inserts on a UUID will almost always go "between" records, which is expensive.  However, Postgres does not support clustered indexes so the underlying data is not ordered.

There are downsides to integers:

- There are a finite number, although big ints pretty much solve that problem.
- They encode order-of-insertion information.  Actually, this can be a positive or a negative.

Other than space usage, I don't think there is much harm in using UUIDs on a static table.  I strongly prefer integers, only resorting to UUIDs in situations where an integer would be difficult to calculate.